# change permission /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, hosts

I'm getting into Vagrant and I installed a plugin that update my Mac's `/etc/hosts` to add a domain and map the IP address to the domain. The only problem that in order to change the file, it needs admin access.

Is it safe to set the permissions of `/etc/hosts` to 664, where the owner and group has read and write access and everyone else can read?

Or should I use 644 where the owner has read and write and everyone else has read access?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to set the permissions of `/etc/hosts` to 664, where the owner and group has read and write access and everyone else can read?

It depends on how well you maintain the system. Basically it shouldn't be a problem, especially as you are free to change the file group-membership to a single-user-group for your account only (if there were processes reading the file using default `4` permission for group, they would access now using the same permission for others).

Nevertheless, if you use Vagrant Hostmanager plugin, there are clear [instructions](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager#passwordless-sudo) how to remove the necessity to provide password at run-time, by adding some configuration to sudoers file:

> Add the following snippet to the sudoers file (e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant_hostmanager`):
>
> ```
> Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE = /bin/cp <home-directory>/.vagrant.d/tmp/hosts.local /etc/hosts
> %<admin-group> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE
> ```
>
> Replace `<home-directory>` with your actual home directory (e.g. `/home/joe`) and `<admin-group>` with the group that is used by the system for sudo access (usually `sudo` on Debian/Ubuntu systems and wheel on Fedora/Red Hat systems).
>
> If necessary, add yourself to the `<admin-group>`:
>
> ```
> usermod -aG <admin-group> <user-name>
> ```
>
> Replace `<admin-group>` with the group that is used by the system for sudo access (see above) and `<user-name>` with you user name.

Comment: I'm looking into passwordlesssudo. The command: `Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE = /bin/cp <home-directory>/.vagrant.d/tmp/hosts.local /etc/hosts
%<admin-group> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE` is confusing to me. Where do I put it, on the Vagrant or my mac?

Comment: On your host Mac, you should run `sudo visudo` command which will open a file for editing and add the line to the appropriate section (order is important, so look for similar lines). ..Just please always use `visudo` for editing and do not edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. `visudo` performs additional checks and will prevent locking yourself out of your machine.

Comment: Added the command, didn't do anything. Also, `sudo nano visudo` produced a blank file while `sudo visudo` wasn't and everytime I try to edit the file, I get a notice asking to open either the read only file or edited. Everything I'm doing is correct so far?

Comment: `sudo nano visudo` is wrong. Frankly, your last comment is grammatically incomprehensible.

Comment: Sorry, it was 4AM when I wrote the comment and I'm starting to get frustrated.  I have this at the top of the file: `Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE = /bin/cp /home/gregoryschultz/.vagrant.d/tmp/hosts.local /etc/hosts
%wheel ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE`. Doesn't do anything. Also I get this message when I edit `visudo`:

Comment: `E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Mon Jul  4 14:00:45 2016
         file name: /private/etc/sudoers.tmp
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: Gregorys-MacBook-Pro.local
        process ID: 503 (still running)
While opening file "/etc/sudoers.tmp"
             dated: Mon Jul  4 16:15:48 2016
      NEWER than swap file!`

Comment: My vagrantfile: `config.vm.network "private_network", ip:"172.28.128.3"
config.vm.hostname = "openbayou.dev"
config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
config.hostmanager.manage_guest = true`

Comment: (1) `Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE = /bin/cp /home/gregoryschultz/.vagrant.d/tmp/hosts.local /etc/hosts %wheel ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_HOSTMANAGER_UPDATE` are **two lines** that you need to **add to `sudoers`** file. (2) You should always edit `sudoers` with the command `sudo visudo`. (3) "*ATTENTION*" message means either you are running `visudo` more than once, or killed it before. You need to correct it now, probably by removing `/etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp`, there are questions how to deal with that message on SuperUser and other SE (4) `Vagrantfile` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Still didn't work. Removed the `.tmp.swp`. Did `sudo visudo` in Terminal. File was saved as `/etc/sudoers.tmp`

Comment: Very good. It should be saved as `/etc/sudoers.tmp` because that's how `visudo` works.

Comment: Kindly please notice, that you asked about permissions for /etc/hosts on a Q&A site. If you have problems with the plugin you use, please file an issue on GitHub or whatever other means of contact with plugin authors/maintainers. This discussion has nothing to do with your original question now. If you have other questions for StackExchange, please ask another question.

Comment: I got it to work! I changed the ownership of `/etc/hosts` from root to me. Only problem is now it won't delete the record when I power down the Vagrant.

Comment: I've moved on to hostupdater which does everything I need it to do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: note what line should be added to the Hosts file, then use Textwrangler to edit the Hosts file: then the permissions are not changed.